# How can I watch for new files in a Docker volume using Python?

Tags: python, docker, event-handling, docker-volume, watchdog

I have a Python script that watches for new files in a directory on my local machine using the watchdog package and uploads them to a remote server. The code works fine when I run it on my local machine, but now I want to run it inside a Docker container, where the files will be stored in a volume mounted to the container.

The problem is that my current implementation of the watchdog script doesn't work with Docker volumes. I suspect that this is because the FileSystemEventHandler class is not detecting the new files in the volume.

I tried to modify the path argument of the Observer object to the mounted path of the Docker volume, but this didn't work. I expected the script to detect the new files in the volume and upload them to the remote server, just like it does on my local machine. However, when I run the script inside the Docker container, it doesn't seem to detect any new files in the volume.

Here's the relevant code:

```
class NewFileHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_created(self, event):
        if event.is_directory:
            return
        file_path = event.src_path
        file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)
        upload_file(file_path, file_name)
```

```
if args.watch_new == 'True':
    print(f"Waiting for new files in directory {directory}...")
    sys.stdout.flush()

    event_handler = NewFileHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, directory, recursive=True)
    observer.start()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            sys.stdout.flush()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

where directory is a volume mounted from .env by docker-compose.yml:

```
    volumes:
      - "${DIRECTORY}:/data"
```

Comment: There's a problem with Windows and WSL where the inotify events aren't sent to the container, if you run that?

Comment: @HansKilian yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured that the polling method works in this case.

```
def get_file_list(directory): 
    return [f for f in os.listdir(directory) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(directory, f))]

def wait_new_files(directory): 
    previous_files = get_file_list(directory)
    while True:
        current_files = get_file_list(directory)
        new_files = list(set(current_files) - set(previous_files))
        for new_file in new_files:
            print("New file created:", new_file)
            file_path = os.path.join(directory, new_file)
            file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)
            upload_file(file_path, file_name)
        previous_files = current_files
        time.sleep(1)
```

Does anyone know of other ways to monitor a Docker volume for changes, or is the polling method the only viable option in this case?

Comment: Polling is the only way, unfortunately. There's this open issue on the problem, but it's been open for 3-4 years and I don't think it's getting fixed: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4739. If you can switch your host OS from Windows to Linux, then it'll work but that's usually not an option.